# Which version of python am I using?

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu

Ubuntu showing me two different versions of python. Which am I using when I call it?

```
$ python --version
  2.7.6
$ python2.7 --version
  2.7.14
```

I installed 2.7.14 from tarball. It is the version I want to use  and want python commands to reference it. How can I do this?

```
 $ whereis python

python: /usr/src/Python-2.7.14/python /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.5-config /usr/bin/python3.6m /usr/bin/python3.4-config /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3.4m /usr/bin/python3.5m-config /usr/bin/python3.5m /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python3.4 /usr/bin/python3.6-config /usr/bin/python3.6m-config /usr/bin/python3.4m-config /etc/python2.7 /etc/python /etc/python3.6 /etc/python3.5 /etc/python3.4 /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.6 /usr/lib/python3.5 /usr/lib/python3.4 /usr/bin/X11/python2.7 /usr/bin/X11/python /usr/bin/X11/python3.5-config /usr/bin/X11/python3.6m /usr/bin/X11/python3.4-config /usr/bin/X11/python3.6 /usr/bin/X11/python3.4m /usr/bin/X11/python3.5m-config /usr/bin/X11/python3.5m /usr/bin/X11/python3.5 /usr/bin/X11/python3.4 /usr/bin/X11/python3.6-config /usr/bin/X11/python3.6m-config /usr/bin/X11/python3.4m-config /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/python2.7-config /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.6 /usr/local/lib/python3.5 /usr/local/lib/python3.4 /usr/include/python3.6m /usr/include/python3.6 /usr/include/python3.4m /usr/include/python3.5m /usr/include/python3.5 /usr/include/python3.4 /usr/share/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz


$ which python
 /usr/bin/python
$ which python2.7
 /usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

Comment: what does `which python` output?

Comment: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv - python version manager could be helpful

Comment: I would do `ls -l $(which python)`... It could be a symlink